# Qlikview - How users to see documents which are assigned to them

Tags: qlikview, access-point

I have 10 qlikview app in AccessPoint and for specific user i want to show only 7 app.
I don't wont to use Section Access.

I use NTFS authorization

[image: Untitled1.png]

And on folder Production (where save qvw app for browser) in Properties Security i remove specific user but he still see app...

How can I handle this?

Comment: I'm no AD specialist but I think the security settings on the actual apps might be overriding the folder settings. Check to see if the apps have the excluded users or some other group associated with them

Answer (score 0):

By your description it sounds like you are using publisher.

If you want to display certain QVW's to certain users, then you need to setup the distribution to "Named Users", that way you can only add users to the relevant apps and the people that are not named will not see the QVW on the accesspoint. 
Also make sure on the actual QVW (right click on it, properties, security) that only the relevant people have security rights on the file.